# Deleting a row based on ID from a local csv file - javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm not a super experienced coder, so forgive me if the question is rather too simple.
I have a csv with many rows, and one of its columns is 'id'. How can I remove just one row based on the id (i.e. code should search for id and delete that row)?

I got the following so far (not too helpful since on one day I may need to remove id 5 and on another I may need to remove id 2...) Thank you so much!

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data)
{
    if (err)
    {
        // check and handle err
    }
    var linesExceptFirst = data.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n');
    fs.writeFile(filename, linesExceptFirst);
});
```

PS: it must be in javascript as the code is running on a nodejs server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to parse the CSV which is simple with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Then you'll need to use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the column value you are after.

It is just a couple lines of code and you are all set:

```
var fs = require('fs')
// Set this up someplace 
var idToSearchFor = 2;
// read the file
fs.readFile('csv.csv', 'utf8', function(err, data)
{
    if (err)
    {
        // check and handle err
    }
    // Get an array of comma separated lines`
    let linesExceptFirst = data.split('\n').slice(1);
    // Turn that into a data structure we can parse (array of arrays)
    let linesArr = linesExceptFirst.map(line=>line.split(','));
    // Use filter to find the matching ID then return only those that don't matching
    // deleting the found match
    // Join then into a string with new lines
    let output = linesArr.filter(line=>parseInt(line[0]) !== idToSearchFor).join("\n");
    // Write out new file
    fs.writeFileSync('new.csv', output);
});
```

Note that I removed the call to `.join()` so we can operate on the array created from the call to `.split()`. The rest is commented.

And finally, a working example can be found here: https://repl.it/@randycasburn/Parse-CSV-and-Find-row-by-column-value-ID

EDIT: The code will now return all rows *except* the found id. Hence, in essence, deleting the row. (Per OPs comment request).

EDIT2: Now outputting to new CSV file per request.

Comment: Make sure the IDs are integers in the first column

Comment: Yes, If the OP wants something else I'll be happy to change the sample.

Comment: Hey @RandyCasburn, I've tried running your working example. It's printing the row I want to extract. How can I actually delete it from the CSV?

Comment: @MichelBergel -  Easy peasy. I've updated the answer - find the **Edit** at the bottom. Change one character: `parseInt(line[0]) !== idToSearchFor)` - so `!==` will return every except the found id! Cool!

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you so much! Would you know why running `fs.writeFile('csv.csv', linesArr.filter(line=>parseInt(line[0]) !== idToSearchFor))` wouldn't work as expected? (It rewrites everything in one row...)

Comment: @MichelBergel -  of course - repl updated. Now that we are writing to a file again we now need to go back to `.join("\n") that you had originally. Should have done that for you originally, but one step at a time works :-)

Comment: So glad to help! Have fun.